# Problem setting up ENVIED package in Flutter to hide API key

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, obfuscation, api-key

I want to use an API key in my flutter app, and have read that the [envied](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) package is a good tool to keep the API key hidden.

The issue is I can't get this working. This is what I've done:

1. Installed the 3 packages:

```
$ flutter pub add envied
$ flutter pub add --dev envied_generator
$ flutter pub add --dev build_runner
```

2. Created a file in the root folder named .env to store the key

```
API_KEY=1234567890
```

3. Created a class in lib/env/env.dart

```
import 'package:envied/envied.dart';

part 'env.g.dart';

@Envied(path: '.env')
abstract class Env {
  @EnviedField(varName: 'API_KEY')
  static final apiKey = _Env.apiKey;
}
```

4. Then run:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

And then I get this error:

```
[SEVERE] envied_generator:envied on lib/env/env.dart:

Envied can only handle types such as `int`, `double`, `num`, `bool` and `String`. Type `InvalidType` is not one of them.
  ╷
9 │   static final apiKey = _Env.apiKey;
```

And a env.g.dart file is not generated.

I have tried a few times and from what I can tell I am following the set up on pub.dev exactly, so not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the obfuscator to work, you need to specify a variable type. Example:

```
static final String apiKey = _Env.apiKey;
```

Comment: This does remove the error indeed, but the env.g.dart file is not generated

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i.e. I used `API_KEY=...`.

Changing to `APIKEY` (without underscore) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Envied can only handle types such as `int`, `double`, `num`, `bool` and `String`. Type `InvalidType` is not one of them.

If you got this kind of error: It simply saying you need to declare the type:

```
static final String key = _Env.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error when I was trying to nest my files into a lower folder

```
lib/util/env/env.dart
```

This didn't work but the generator ran when I changed my file location to the following:

```
lib/env/env.dart
```