# Flutter ENVied package build runner error

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

The problem I am facing is with [ENVied](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) package for flutter. I am trying to save my api keys in environment variables.

I followed these steps.

1. Installed these three packages

```
$ flutter pub add envied
$ flutter pub add --dev envied_generator
$ flutter pub add --dev build_runner
```

2. I created .env file and saved my api key in it.
   [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daexl.png)
3. After this, I created the env.dart file with the following code:

```
import 'package:envied/envied.dart';

part 'env.g.dart';

@Envied(path: '.env')
abstract class Env {
  @EnviedField(varName: 'TEST_KEY')
  static final String apiKey = _Env.apiKey;
}
```

4. Then I ran the build runner command.
   `dart run build_runner build`

After this command I faced the error saying
`Envied requires types to be explicitly declared. 'apiKey' does not declare a type.`

5. So I made changes in my code and declared a type of String and ran the command again.

Now I faced another build runner error stating
`Environment variable not found for field 'apiKey'.`

And a env.g.dart file is not generated.

I have tried a few times and from what I can tell I am following the set up on pub.dev exactly, so not sure how to fix it. I checked out the possible issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641403/problem-setting-up-envied-package-in-flutter-to-hide-api-key) but still none of those responses helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:envied/envied.dart';

part 'env.g.dart';

@Envied(path: '.env') //give full path here with name like secret.env instead of only extension
abstract class Env {
@EnviedField(varName: 'varNameHere')
static String varNameHere = _Env.varNameHere;
}
```

the variables name should be the same at all three places. Here in your case your varName is 'TEST_KEY', and variable storing name is apikey. so replace all three places with same name as in example above and run command:

```
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

this will generate all files necessary & follow the pub.dev envied instructions. This article may be helpful [securing API keys in flutter](https://dev.to/namankk/securely-storing-api-keys-in-flutter-3ko4)